# Python: use request to get the result of auto suggestion from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, autosuggest

I am looking at [this web page](http://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm?fromsearch=1). 
In that page, there is a small box that says `GET QUOTE`.

If I for example type `AMD` the auto-suggestion opens up and shows a list like this:
[image]

My question is how to use request in Python3 to get this list, meaning to get:

```
AMD      Advanced Micro Devices
AMDA     Amedia Corp
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use browser's debugging facility to see what's going on when you request, and what you've got. For example, in Chrome, you can use *Network* tab of *Developer Tools* to see what request/response are made.

[image: Chromium - Developer Tools - Network]

---

Use `json` parameter to send `application/json` request, and use `Response.json()` to decode the json response text:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://research.investors.com/services/AutoSuggest.asmx/GetQuoteResults'
>>> response = requests.post(url, json={'q':'AMD','limit':10})
>>> data = response.json()
>>> [row['Symbol'] for row in data['d']]
['AMD', 'AMDA', 'DOX']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it works beautifully.